# Struts2: method attribute in <s:submit> button doesn't work

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, submit-button, struts-action

I have a form in jsp. There are two submit buttons: "Search" and "Add New" button. I had set each button with their own method attribute.

```xml
<s:form name="searchForm" action="employeeAction" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="id" label="Employee ID"/>
    <s:textfield name="name" label="Employee Name"/>

    <s:submit value="Search" method="doSearch"/>
    <s:submit value="Add New" method="doAddNew"/>
</s:form>
```

In struts.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>

    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

        <default-action-ref name="index" />

        <global-results>
            <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        </global-results>

        <global-exception-mappings>
            <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error"/>
        </global-exception-mappings>

    </package>

    <package name="example" namespace="/example" extends="default">

        <action name="employeeAction" class="example.EmployeeAction">
           <result name="search">/example/search.jsp</result>
           <result name="add">/example/add.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

In EmployeeAction class

```
public class EmployeeAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EmployeeAction.class);

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {    
        logger.info("Calling execute!");    
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String doSearch() throws Exception {    
        logger.info("Calling doSearch!");    
        return "search";
    }

    public String doAddNew() throws Exception {    
        logger.info("Calling doAddNew!");    
        return "add";
    }
}
```

The problem is when I clicked **"Search"** or **"Add New"** button, the method **doSearch()** or **doAddNew()** was never called, instead it called method **execute()**. What is wrong with my code above?

I'm using struts v2.3.

Comment: `method` should not mean `POST or GET`?

Comment: method of s:form is http method, method of s:submit is Struts2 Action method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set

```xml
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
```

to

```xml
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true" />
```

Another way is to define multiple mappings for the same Action, like

in JSP:

```xml
<s:submit value="Search"  action="employeeSearchAction" />
<s:submit value="Add New" action="employeeAddNewAction"/>
```

in Struts.xml

```xml
<action name="employeeSearchAction" class="example.EmployeeAction" method="doSearch">
       <result>/example/search.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="employeeAddNewAction" class="example.EmployeeAction" method="doAddNew">
       <result>/example/add.jsp</result>
</action>
```

A third way is to use [Wildcard Mappings](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Wildcard+Mappings).

P.S: If you go for the second one, I'll suggest, as a best practice, to use one Action for every logical action you have to perform...

If you have common data loaded / managed by both your actions, "search" and "addNew",
then you can define a employeeBaseAction, extended by both employeeSearchAction and employeeAddNewAction.

---

## EDIT

It's 2014 now, and **DMI usage is unanimously discouraged** (today more than ever), other than pretty useless, so I **strongly** suggest you to use solution n.2.