# How to use search and save button in struts2 form?

Tags: java, jsp, methods, struts2, model-driven

Here is my form

```xml
  <s:form action="changeStatus">
    <s:div class="table">
        <s:textfield name="custId" label="CUSTOMER ID" />
        <s:textfield name="lifewardsCard" label="LIFE WARDS CARD NUMBER"
            size="20" />
        <s:textfield name="clientNo" label="CLIENT NUMBER" />
        <s:textfield name="custName" label="CUSTOMER NAME" />
        <s:textfield name="cardExpiryDate" label="CARD EXPIRY DATE(MMYYYY)" />
        <s:select name="status" label="CARD STATUS"
            list="#{'1':'Active', '2':'Inactive'}" />
        <tr>
            <td><s:submit value="search" theme="simple" /></td>
            <td><s:submit value="save" theme="simple" /></td>
            <td><s:submit type="button" theme="simple"
                    onclick="clear();return false;" value="clear" /></td>
        </tr>
    </s:div>
</s:form>
```

user will input the field custID and clicks search button
I am able to get the values from database and show them on the page
but what I wanted to do is after displaying the data he can edit the data and should be able to save the data by clicking save button.
here's my xml configuration

```xml
<action name="changeStatus" class="com.struts.lifewardscard.ChangeAction">
    <result name="input">ChangeCardStatus.jsp</result>  
    <result name="success">ChangeCardStatus.jsp</result>
</action>
```

and here is my action class

```
public class ChangeAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven {
    CardStatusForm cardSform=new CardStatusForm();
    public String execute() throws Exception{
        String clientId=null;
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        getCardHolderDetails();     
        return "success";

    }

    private void getCardHolderDetails() {
        Connection c = null;
        Boolean empty = true;
        DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S");

        // Format date into output format
        DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        try {
            c = Conexion.getConnection();
            CallableStatement cst = c
                    .prepareCall("{call P_GET_CARD_DETAIILS(?,?)}");
            cst.setString(1, cardSform.getCustId());
            cst.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            cst.executeUpdate();
            ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) cst.getObject(2);
            while (rs.next()) {
                cardSform.setLifewardsCard(rs.getString(1));
                cardSform.setClientNo(rs.getString(2));
                if(rs.getString(3).equalsIgnoreCase("active"))
                {
                    cardSform.setStatus(1);
                }else
                {
                    cardSform.setStatus(2);
                }

                cardSform.setCustName(rs.getString(4));
                cardSform.setCardExpiryDate(rs.getString(5));
                System.out.println(inputFormat.parse(rs.getString(6)));
                empty = false;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


    @Override
    public Object getModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return cardSform;
    }
}
```

even though I can write a method that can save the data in action class I dont find a way to call that method with out calling the other method `getCardHolderDetails()`.

Comment: @AleksandrM Can you elaborate how to use `method:` prefix and why OP didn't use it in his/her question? I *really* love to use this prefix instead of ugly `action:` or better without any prefixes.

Comment: @RomanC: Where did you find method prefix in those questions? ;) Anyway from the docs: *To use method attribute (to use multiple submit buttons which direct to different action methods) you must set struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation to true but this can lead to security vulnerability - use with care!*.

Comment: @AleksandrM The linked one by you, and yes that docs is correct...

Comment: @RomanC: Nope. There isn't any reference to method prefix.

Comment: @RomanC: method="add" is form struts.xml which has nothing to do with method prefix. There were no setting for action prefix prior to `2.3.15.3` and my answer dates way back that time. :)

Comment: @AleksandrM Oops, my bad reading, sorry :|.

Comment: @RomanC: It happens. Don't worry. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define an **action** for each *logical action* you need to perform.

Multiple actions can reside

- in different Java classes (eg `ReadCardAction.java`, `UpdateCardAction.java`, etc.) or
- in a single Java class with multiple methods (eg. `CardAction.java` with `read()` and `update()`).

Using a single Java class can be handy if you need to share common logic and helper methods, otherwise you can exploit the inheritance to achieve the same with single files, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13530194/1654265).

To call two different actions from within a single form, there are three ways:

1. Using the `action` attribute:

   ```xml
   <s:submit value="search"                     />
   <s:submit value="save"   action="saveStatus" />
   ```

   This way, <kbd>search</kbd> will call form's action method (`changeStatus`), that will default to `execute()`, while <kbd>save</kbd> will call `saveStatus` action, that you will map to an `update()` method:

   ```xml
   <action name="changeStatus" class="com.struts.lifewardscard.ChangeAction">        
       <result name="success">ChangeCardStatus.jsp</result>
       <result name="input">ChangeCardStatus.jsp</result>  
   </action>

   <action name="saveStatus" class="com.struts.lifewardscard.ChangeAction" method="update">
       <result name="success">ChangeCardStatus.jsp</result>
       <result name="input">ChangeCardStatus.jsp</result>  
   </action>
   ```

   To do this on Struts2 > 2.3.15.2 you need to **activate the action prefix** in struts.xml [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21603806/1654265).
2. Changing the target of the form with Javascript on button click;

   - when clicking <kbd>search</kbd>, point to `changeStatus`,
   - when clicking <kbd>save</kbd>, point to `saveStatus`.

   You will find [thousands of examples of how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1925625/1654265).
3. [Dynamic Method Invocation (DMI)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13336391/1654265). Discouraged, deprecated, ***do not try this at home***. I'm just including it for completeness, because you could get into it in the future while reading someone else's legacy code, and saying "whut ?".

Comment: But basically 1. it is DMI :) And we are working hard to bring DMI back :)

Comment: Well, sort of @LukaszLenart, DMI lets you call an action's method, the action prefix is much less powerful, allowing you just to call a mapped action. I'd rather call it half-DMI... it still sounds weird to manually changing the target with javascript *every* time, sounds too hackishly un-automatic, but I guess that a vanilla javascript changing the target could be generated directly by the theme(s) for `<s:submit action="foo" />` in a transparent way... that would be interesting. My 2 cents obviously

Answer (score 2):

Another way

Use the `name` attribute and the pressed button will be included in the request

```xml
<td><s:submit name="search" value="search" theme="simple" /></td>
<td><s:submit name="save"   value="save"   theme="simple" /></td>
```

Execute method

```
 public String execute() throws Exception{
        String clientId=null;
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        if (request.getParameter("search") != null) {
          // search button pressed   
           ....
        } else if (request.getParameter("save") != null) {
          // save button pressed
           ....
        }
        return "success";
 }
```

Comment: Yeat, this is the fourth way, however better than the DMI one